# Working in the EU: I come from USA and I have Italian passport

Tags: eu-citizens, eu, visa, documentation

I recently got my citizenship in Italy through jus sanguinis. I live in the USA, but have an Italian birth certificate and passport. How hard would it be now for me to get a job in the EU? And by hard I don't mean the actual task of finding the job and applying but the work associated with getting a working visa. I realize that this may vary from country to country, but if I wanted to work in the Netherlands, or the UK would that be readily possible?

Comment: You can work anywhere in the EU with an Italian passport, make the most of it :)

Comment: As everyone already noted, you can freely work in EU as Italian citizen; what I didn't see noted anywhere is that you can't forget to register your residency in the local governments office and then in the local Italian consulate (you are or SHOULD currently be registered in the AIRE of your local Italian consulate in the US). You can/must register and pay your taxes in your EU country of residency too without any special requirements from Italy.

Answer (score 12):

As an Italian citizen, you do not need a working visa for the Netherlands, as it is also in the [European Union](https://ind.nl/en/individuals/residence-wizard/eu/registration-for-eu-citizens):

> All EU/EEA or Swiss citizens, with the exception of Croatians, are entitled to work without restriction in all sectors and industries.

The same holds true for the [UK](http://www.hmrc.gov.uk/migrantworkers/documents.htm#A2), where you need neither a visa nor a work permit.

This is linked to the [Freedom of movement to work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizenship_of_the_European_Union#Free_movement_rights) inside the European Union.

Comment: +1 Even registering might be optional depending on the country and should in any case just be a formality after you found a job. Basically, you can just show up and start looking for a job.

Comment: "You just need to register" -- actually you don't *need to* anymore. At least not with IND (the immigration's). You do have to register with municipality, but that's something even locals have to do.

Comment: Yes, I misread the document. I changed it. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Coincidentally you're in a very similar situation I was/am in.

In Europe, as [drat explains](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/1053/373), you do not need any working visa. In the Netherlands, you have to register in the "Town Hall" (Gemeente) of the city you're establishing in. You should not have any language issues as most people talk english (I'd say that more people speak English in Amsterdam than in London). Opening a bank account requires your passport and a copy of a paper given to you by the Gemeente stating that you live there now.

In the UK you need to register in the JobCentre Plus in order to get a National Insurance Number (NI for short), which will be needed in order to be properly taxed in any job you take (but you can work for up to three months before getting it, you just get taxed at the highest rate, and later reimbursed once you give you NI to your employer), as well to be able to open a bank account.